# Make global function known for imported function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am writing an IPythonNotebook and to make my code less clustered, I am defining some functions not in the main notebook. I outplace them in external .py-files which I import.

Why doesn't `test()` know of `u()`?

In the myModule.py-file

```
def test():
    number = u()+u()
    return number
```

And my main file (in the notebook)

```
from myModul import test

def u():
    bla = 1
    return bla


test()
```

My `test()`-function is imported well, but does not know `u`:

NameError: global name 'u' is not defined

Comment: Globals are **per module**; if globals from other modules could be found you'd end up with hard-to-find bugs. What if `def u()` was already defined in `myModule`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this; globals are only ever looked up in the module the function is defined in.

You'd instead give your function a parameter that accepts `u` as an argument:

```
def test(u):
    number = u()+u()
    return number
```

and in the main file:

```
def u():
    bla = 1
    return bla

test(u)
```

If Python worked the way you expected it to, you'd create many hard-to-trace problems, which namespaces (like modules) were meant to solve in the first place.

Comment: @user2366975: yes, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

python does not have the idea of global functions - functions exist in modules. Even variables are only global inside a module, and can't be seen by any other module unless they are imported.

so if you want your test function to be able to see your function "U" - you either need to : 
1) import your mainmodule into myModul - not a great idea as you end up with circular dependencies.

2) Follow Martijn Pieters excellent idea of passing function u into your test function

3) Think about the organisation of your code - if your "test" function really depends on calling "u" then should they be defined in the different modules ?

Comment: I agree. But that leads me to the question if python is suitable for any project containing more than - say - 5000 loc.

Comment: @user2366975: Why wouldn't Python be suitable to large projects? Python itself is 430k LOC *in Python code alone*, for example; the project codebase is about 50/50 Python and C..

Comment: Projects of that size should not be relying on global anything in my view (and I have several projects well over 5000 loc with no global data). using OOP principles, layered application design and techniques like passing functions as objects make such projects not only viable but easier to develop and test.